# What exactly does a MIPS lw instruction do?

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

Help! I am new to assembly and I am trying to find out what this command does

```
lw %t5, 100($t8)
```

Also I understand that the left is the destination and the right is the source

```
lw Reg.Dest, Offset(Reg.Source)
```

I believe that it write data from one place to another but I do not understand the details.

Could someone please explain the command to me or point me to the right direction?

Comment: It loads the value at `$t8 + 100` into register `$t5`

Comment: `%t5` is a syntax error.  I assume you mean `$t5`?

Answer (score 3):

`lw` is shorthand for "load word", which is what the instruction does -- it loads(reads) a word of data from memory into a register.

The first operand (the destination) is thus a register, while the second specifies a location in memory.  The location (address) is computed by adding an offset to the contents of a register.

Answer (score 1):

The following definition you provided is correct.

```
lw Reg.Dest, Offset(Reg.Source)
```

Let's translate this to your code.

```
lw $t5, 100($t8)
```

Here we have the Load Word (lw) instruction, with `Reg.Dest = $t5`, `Offset = 100`, and `Reg.Source = $t8`.

So altogether, this is saying *Load 4 bytes at address `$t8 + 100` into register $t5*

Answer (score 0):

`lw` is an I-Type instruction:

```
  +--------+----+----+-----------+
I | opcode | rs | rt | immediate |   (instruction fields)
  +--------+----+----+-----------+
       6     5     5      16         (bit length)
```

It has the following specification in RTL ([register transfer level/logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level)):

```
R[rt] = M[R[rs]+SignExtImm]
```

where

```
SignExtImm = { 16{immediate[15]}, immediate }
```

The assembly syntax is `lw rt, immediate(rs)` where `rt`, `rs`, and `immediate` are register names and a small integer constant, respectively.

See the [MIPS green sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) for all the instructions.

Note that `lw` opcode also generally supports a number of pseudo instruction forms, which expand into multiple actual MIPS instructions.  To see what those do, we can examine the individual instructions of the expansion.  One form is particularly useful to load global variables: `lw rt, globalDataLabel`.  In this form, no base register (`rs`) is provided.  It expands into 2 instructions that accomplish loading the global word into the target register.